# problems with C++11-library and g++ 4.4.7

Tags: c++, random

I am working on a server with GCC version 4.4.7, and I am forced to work with this version unfortunately. I want to make use of the `<random>` library of C++0x, but I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10061174/1710373) that in this version `uniform_real_distribution` is called `uniform_real`. When I try to call this function and `normal_distribution`, I don't get useful output. See this example:

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    typedef std::mt19937 Engine;
    typedef std::uniform_real<double> Dis1;
    typedef std::normal_distribution<double> Dis2;

    Engine eng(0);

    Dis1 dis1(0, 1);
    cout << dis1(eng) << endl; //OUTPUTS 3.49921e+09

    Dis2 dis2(0, 1);
    cout << dis2(eng) << endl; //STALLS, NO OUTPUT

    return 0;
}
```

I compile with `g++44 -std=c++0x main.cpp` and I have shown what output I get. What is the issue here?

Comment: 4.4 is rather old, especially when it comes to c++11 conformance.

Comment: Anything before 4.7 is pretty sparse for C++11 support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[C++11 support in gcc 4.4](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.4/cxx0x_status.html) is rather sparse.

The [release notes for gcc 4.5](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.5/changes.html) include

> Improved experimental support for the upcoming ISO C++ standard,
>   C++0x

specifically mentioning `<random>`.